# WildFly - Adding JARs to classpath

Tags: oracle, ssl, jboss, classpath, wildfly

I am using WildFly 8.2.1.

I need to add specific JAR files to the class path. How can I do that?

Do I need to get inside the module hell?

All I need is to add a couple of extra Oracle JAR files to enable using TLS on the data source connection...

Comment: Modules are easy, at least as far as adding jdbc drivers was concerned.

Comment: You are correct. There are not as horrible as I thought they would be however. It still is not working: it looks like the jars are not added in classpath (my Oracle won't connect TLS-ly, it fails with an error that shows when the specific JARs are not in classpath) ... but on the other hand, when I introduce a typo on purpose in my JAR list, WildFly complains,... so they must be loaded somehow...)

Comment: Why not just put them in the .war file? I think if they are added as modules you have to make resources or something out of them. With jdbc dirvers, for example, you have to declare the modules in the configuration file as drivers and add them to a datasource.

Answer (score 0):

When you build your .war file, add them to the /WEB-INF/lib directory. They will be accessible on the classpath from there. In eclipse the eclipse maven plugin, m2e, will do it by reading your POM file, or of course, maven run by hand will do it.

In the POM file, have it packaged as a war

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

and declare your jar as a dependency.